# How to make "INNER JOIN" sql query based on my requirements

Tags: php, mysql, yii, inner-join

i have 3 tables in my db:

**countries**

```
id INT
name VARCHAR
```

**client_passport_countries**

```
id INT
client_passport_id INT
countries_id INT
```

**client_passport**

```
id INT
name VARCHAR
```

I want to choose **countries:** *name* where the **countries**:*id* = **client_passport_countries**:*countries_id*
and **client_passport**:*id* = **client_passport_countries**:*client_passport_id*.

How can I achieve this using INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Maybe some application can generate this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You just need to join what you said.

```
SELECT aa.name
FROM countries AS aa
INNER JOIN client_passport_countries AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.countries_id
INNER JOIN client_passport AS cc
ON bb.client_passport_id = cc.id
ORDER BY aa.name;
```

Comment: and what if i want to show countries by client_passport->id = 9 for example?

Comment: Then you need a WHERE clause like this: WHERE bb.client_passport_id = 9 ORDER BY aa.name

Comment: I 'm glad that I helped you.